# Leer XML desde Unity

Tags: xml, unity3d

¡Buenas!
Tengo una pequeña aplicación en `Unity`, y necesito leer ficheros `XML`.

Mi código `XML` es muy simple:

```
<libro> 
  <libroEjemplo> 
       <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
       <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
  </libroEjemplo>

  <libroEjemplo> 
       <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
       <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
  </libroEjemplo>  
</libro>
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que `Unity` lea el `XML` y guarde en variables los datos de *nombre* y *e-mail*?

Gracias antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa este ejemplo, a mi me ayudo para conocer un poco mas sobre el manejo de xml, saludos

http://unitynoobs.blogspot.mx/2011/02/xml-loading-data-from-xml-file.html

Comment: Amigo te recomiendo que hagas una respuesta mas aceptable